# WIthin github site, where do i find the other repositories coloboraton invites?

Tags: github, github-pages

In GitHub, one of my friend sent me a collaboration invite for their repository.

I was looking in many places within the site,

1. In my account setting, profile page
2. In friends repository page

But nowhere in site i could find the invite, where do i find the invite in the site ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the search of answers, found below solution.

**Note:** Still there is no *straight forward page/section* within the site to navigate(At least, till Mar 2020
).

1. Through mail & site notification - as per [Raju's aswser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60809519/6308826), that is the primary way how the sites collaboration invite works
2. A manual way - There is an URL format, in which you can enter the related details, to see the invites in a webpage as below,

https://github.com/username/reponame/invitations

username => the complete & exact, GitHub profile name from whom, you expect the invite

reponame => the complete & exact, repository name to which you are invited to collaborate

[For more on this, refer this thread from their community support](https://github.community/t5/How-to-use-Git-and-GitHub/Where-do-I-see-all-incoming-invitations-collaborator/td-p/4280)

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, the request comes as a notification. Once you click on it, it will take you to a page where you can accept and reject.

Please check if he has invited correct person.